# Hive sql: count and avg

Tags: sql, count, hive, average

I'm recently trying to learn Hive and i have a problem with a sql consult.
I have a json file with some information. I want to get the average for each register. Better in example:

```
country  times
USA      1
USA      1
USA      1
ES       1
ES       1
ENG      1
FR       1
```

then with next consult:

```
select country, count(*) from data;
```

I obtain:

```
country   times
USA        3
ES         2
ENG        1 
FR         1
```

then i should get next out:

```
country   avg
USA       0,42  (3/7)
ES        0,28  (2/7)
ENG       0,14  (1/7)
FR        0,14  (1/7)
```

I don't know how i can obtain this out from the first table.

I tried:

```
select t1.country, avg(t1.tm), 
from (
    select country,count(*)as tm from data where not country is null group by country
) t1
group by t1.country;
```

but my out is wrong.

Thanks for help!! BR.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the each group count by total count to get the result. Use `Sub-Query` to find the total number of records in your table

Try this

```
select t1.country, count(*)/IFNULL((select cast(count(*) as float) from data),0)
from data
group by t1.country;
```